# Get a promise that resolves with the next value emitted

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to resolve a promise with the first value emitted since subscribing to an Observable.

I first tried using `.toPromise()`:

```
await observable.toPromise()
```

but that only works when `observer.complete()` is called within the observable.

`take(1)` and `first()` also aren't suitable because they just allow the values to be piped to other observables.

At the moment, I've come up with this code:

```
await new Promise(resolve => {
    const subscription = observable.subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data)
        subscription.unsubscribe()
    })
})
```

Is there a utility function that I'm not using or is there a way to simplify it further?

Comment: Why do you use an observable in the first place? It seems like you should use a promise from the start...

Comment: @trincot I'm feeding the results from an [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) into an Observable.

Comment: what is your concern in regard to  `allowing the values to be piped to other observables.`

Comment: @RafiHenig I want to resolve the value as a promise, not another observable.

Comment: I understand, yet why does it stop you from using `first`,  forcing the observable to complete as soon as value is emitted

Comment: @RafiHenig I'm exporting the observable so I can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `first` operator to have the observable emit the first value and complete.

```
await observable.pipe(first()).toPromise()
```